# In Catalina, `orderFront:` causes app to become the active application; how do I prevent this?

Tags: cocoa, nspanel

I have a background "monitoring" app that runs either as an accessory or as a regular app (user choice depending on whether they want to see it in the dock).

The app has several never-key utility windows (`NSPanel`s) that display the progress of background tasks. When a background task starts, the window is made visible using `orderFront:`.

This has worked great for years; the window would simply appear somewhere behind the active app.

Starting in Catalina (macOS 10.15), however, `orderFront:` causes my monitoring app to become active, stealing the focus from the user's app.

This is bad and I'd like to prevent it, but I can't seem to figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not `-orderFront:`.

It turns out that in Catalina, if you change the app's activation policy to `NSApplicationActivationPolicyRegular`, as some point in the near future (i.e. not immediately), the app will become the active app, just as if it had been launched.

*What was throwing me was the sequence of events: the activation policy changed, the window was created and made front, and then the app became the frontmost app.*

Sadly, since there's no way to refuse becoming the frontmost app my only workaround is to capture the currently active app when I change the activation policy, wait for the activation, then request the original app become the active app again. Ugly, but in my application this should only happen a few times a day; here's hoping the user isn't looking at the screen when it does.